# How do I replace JSON data by sending post request. Currently, the data is appending to existing data

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am pretty new on Angular2 and faced with an issue related to RestAPI. I send post request to the server where located JSON file. I would like to replace existing data in JSON file, but as result, I receive append data.
This is my code:

```
let headers    = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options    = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });    
this.http.post(url, body, options).map((res:Response) => res.json())
.subscribe((body) => body );
```

My JSON file is :

```
  {
    "budget": [
      {
        "service": "electricity",
        "real_amount": 100,
        "expected_amount": 100,
        "id": 0
      }
    ]
 }
```

After and post request was sent, my JSON file started to be

```
 {
  "budger":
  {
        "service": "electricity",
        "real_amount": 100,
        "expected_amount": 100,
        "id": 0
      }
    ],
    {
        "service": "electricity",
        "real_amount": 100,
        "expected_amount": 100,
        "id": 0
      }
    ]
}
```

My ts file :

```
          import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
          import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
          import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
          import {Http, Headers,RequestOptions,Response} from 
         '@angular/http';
          import {ApiService} from './api.service';
          import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

         @Component({
            selector: 'app-root',
           templateUrl: './app.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
            })
            export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

          real_amount: string;
          service: string;
          expected_amount: string;
           public data;
          public real_data;

           constructor(private http: Http) {
             }
            ngOnInit(): void {
           this.http.get("./assets/data/expected_expensives.json")
          .subscribe((data) => {
            this.data = data.json();
            console.log(data.json());
             });
             }
            updateBudget() {
            console.log(this.service +" " + this.real_amount);
              console.log(this.data.budget.length);
              for(let i=0 ; i< this.data.budget.length; i++)
              {
           if (this.data.budget[i].service === this.service)
            {
             console.log(this.data.budget[i].service);
             this.data.budget[i].real_amount=this.real_amount;
            }
         } 

 let body:any = JSON.stringify(this.data.budget);
 let url = "http://localhost:3000/budget";
 let response:any;
 let headers    = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
 let options    = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  this.http.post(url, body, options).map((res:Response) => res.json())
 .subscribe((body) => body );
  }
}
```

MY html file :

```
             <div id="main">
               <div id="right_side">
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label>Choose a service</label>
                  <select  [(ngModel)]="service">    
                    <option *ngFor="let item of data?.budget" 
                       ngDefaultControl >{{item.service}}</option>
                  </select>
                  <label>Enter an amount</label>
                  <input id="real_amount" type="text" 
                  [(ngModel)]="real_amount" ngDefaultControl>
                  <input type="submit" value="Pay" 
                  (click)="updateBudget(service,real_amount)">
                   </div>
                  </div> 
                <div id="left_side">
                   <table>
                    <thead>
                     <th>Service</th>
                     <th>Expected Expencies</th>
                     <th>Real Expencies</th>
                    </thead>
                     <tbody>
                     <tr *ngFor="let item of data?.budget">          
                      <td>{{item.service}}</td>
                      <td>{{item.expected_amount}}</td>
                       <td>{{item.real_amount}}</td>
                     </tr>        
                   </tbody>
                 </table>
           </div>
           </div>
```

Can someone suggest proper solution? 
Regards.

Comment: where is yourexisting data in JSON file located?  Please, put some codes of your ts and service for clarity of question.

Comment: I use json-server , my json.file located on the same place where located package.json. (root folder). I use Fake server

Comment: Do you want to replace existing data in JSON file that is located in your project? But why? What does replace means?

Comment: I show some data from the JSON file on my web page, I update it.But my update only on the web page, so for update the data locally, I have to send post request for make update on the file. Maybe I make mistake?

Comment: What i get is, you have displayed some data on your webpage(template) from a local json file(perhaps in assets folder). Now, you want to update your webpage(html template) by 'post' ajax call  from service and no longer require local json data. Am I right?

Comment: Can you put your ts and html.

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

    export class CcDataServiceService {
 constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

      getLocalData(): Observable<any[]> {
        return this.http.get('assets/data/expected_expensives.json')
          .map(this.extractData)
          .catch(this.handleError);
      }

      getserverData(ajaxdata): Observable<any[]> {
        console.log('ajaxdata::' + JSON.stringify(ajaxdata));
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.post(url, ajaxdata)
          .map(this.extractData)
          .catch(this.handleError);
      }

      private extractData(res: Response) {
        const body = res.json();
        return body || [];
      }

      private handleError(error: any) {
        const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
          error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg);
        console.log('Server Error!');
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
      }
    }
```

### component.ts

```
constructor(public jsonDataService: CcDataServiceService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let thisx = this;

// if you want data from server call getserverData() else getLocalData()
        this.jsonDataService.getserverData().subscribe(
          function (success) {
            thisx.data = success;
           thisx.datahandle(success);
          },
          error => console.log('Getting Server Data Error :: ' + JSON.stringify(error)));


}
datahandle(jsonData){

console.log('check your data' + JSON.stringify(jsonData)); <-----check data
// may parse your data 

let keys = Object.keys(jsonData);
console.log(keys);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ahmad.

Comment: Glad, it helped you. Accept it as answer, if it helped you.